# How can I schedule another task in .NET while the current one is blocking?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, concurrency, task-parallel-library

For my .NET 4.0 project, I am using a custom `TaskScheduler` with a limited degree of concurrency (similar to the [LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx) example on MSDN). A bunch of the tasks it executes block while waiting for some other operation to return a result and then continue with their work. Because it is a shame that the threads of this scheduler don't have anything to do during this period of time, I would like to schedule another task while one blocks.

I thought that maybe the TPL could see when a task blocked and then schedule something else, but my experiments with `Monitor.Wait()` or waiting on a `ManualResetEvent` have shown that this is not the case. Since I am already using my own task scheduler I thought there might be way to tell it explicitly to schedule another task, but I haven't found any method on `Task`, `TaskScheduler` etc. to do so.

Note that continuations won't work here, as I am in the middle of one task executing. Also, I would really like to avoid splitting the tasks into two, a pre-wait and a post-wait task, because there are potentially several points where waiting is required and splitting them all would lead to a level of fragmentation of my original algorithm that would make it hard to maintain. I suppose things like `await` from the Async CTP would be helpful, but I have to stick with .NET 4 for this one.

Is there something I am missing to tell a task scheduler to dequeue the next task and then come back to the current one when that one done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your own `TaskScheduler`, TPL doesn't schedule anything, that's the work of the `TaskScheduler`.

If you want some way to tell your custom `TaskScheduler` to schedule another `Task`, you will have to add it to your `TaskScheduler` by yourself. And you can't execute new `Task` and then “come back” to the old one, because there is no way to pause an executing `Task`.

But the simplest solution might be using the default `TaskScheduler`, since it takes blocked `Task`s into account when deciding how many `Task`s to schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Task.ContinueWith does gives you the option to schedule a task once your initial task is complete or faulted.but this helps only when the initial task has ran to completion.

Comment: I knew about continuations, but I don't think I can use them for this. I have updated my original question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing built-in. To avoid problems like this one, use non-blocking tasks.

You could also slightly oversubscribe the CPU by makign your own custom TaskScheduler run more threads in parallel than there are CPUs. This will lead to light inefficiencies but in case a task blocks, you have other "backfill" task already running and taking over the CPU.